Adding an attribute or class to multiple elements without repeatedly defining the container - jQuery
Been years since I've done any real coding, and I was never great at JS to begin with, so forgive me if this is a dumb question.
How do I add an attribute to multiple elements without having to spell out the container element multiple times? In other words, this works fine:
$('.carousel .content .section.collapsed a[href], .carousel .content .section.collapsed *[tabindex]').attr("inert",""); 

But this doesn't:
$('.carousel .content .section.collapsed')(function() {
    $('a[href], *[tabindex]').attr("inert",""); 
});

I don't want to have to keep adding ".carousel .content .section.collapsed" for every single element in the list.

Use .find() within the container selector:
$('.carousel .content .section.collapsed').find('a[href], [tabindex]').attr("inert", "");


Thank you sir. I figured it was something simple like that.
